# character XOR in Elixir

Tags: elixir

If you `use Bitwise` in Elixir you can XOR two numbers with: `xor(1, 2) == 3`. If I want to take the bytes from a file and XOR them, I *can* do this, but I can't believe this is the most efficient way of doing it! Am I missing something about how character lists work?

```
defmodule Example do
  use Bitwise, skip_operators: true

  def char_xor(a, b) do
    combined = bxor(
      List.first(String.to_charlist(a)),
      List.first(String.to_charlist(b))
    )
    String.Chars.to_string(<<combined>>)
  end
end
```

Which allows the following expression to be true:

```
Example.char_xor("h", "i") == <<1>>
```

Am I missing some facet of Elixir (I'm new!) that makes this simpler?

---

Thanks to @dogbert's fine suggestions below I've gone with:

```
defp char_xor(<<a, as::binary>>, <<b, as::binary>>) do
  <<bxor(a, b)>>
end
```

Comment: Do you want to xor the characters or the bytes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you want `Example.char_xor("h", "i") == <<1>>` and you want to xor the bytes, not chars. I would use a simple recursive function and pattern matching to repeatedly extract the first bytes, xor them, and recurse to process the rest of the binary.

```
defmodule Example do
  use Bitwise, skip_operators: true

  def char_xor(a, b) do
    char_xor(a, b, "")
  end

  def char_xor("", "", acc), do: acc
  def char_xor(<<a, as::binary>>, <<b, bs::binary>>, acc) do
    char_xor(as, bs, <<acc::binary, bxor(a, b)>>)
  end
end
```

```
iex(1)> Example.char_xor("h", "i")
<<1>>
```

Note that this will throw an error if the binaries are of different length. You can choose to handle them by adding more cases to `Example.char_xor/3`.

Comment: Thank you! You've actually solved a more complex problem for me - I only have two arguments (the recursion isn't necessary for my purposes) - I've added what I've gone with to the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to xor two binaries, just use the built-in OTP [`:crypto.exor/2`](https://erlang.org/doc/man/crypto.html#exor-2) function:

```
iex(1)> :crypto.exor("h", "i")
<<1>>
```

Or as a better example:

```
iex(2)> :crypto.exor("ABC", "xyz")
"9;9"
iex(3)> show_bits = fn s -> for(<<x::1 <- s>>, do: "#{x}") |> Enum.chunk_every(8) |> Enum.join(" ") end
#Function<44.79398840/1 in :erl_eval.expr/5>
iex(4)> "ABC" |> show_bits.()
"01000001 01000010 01000011"
iex(5)> "xyz" |> show_bits.()
"01111000 01111001 01111010"
iex(6)> :crypto.exor("ABC", "xyz") |> show_bits.()
"00111001 00111011 00111001"
```